# Is possible to make a division between two queries in Visual Studio Team Services chart?

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard, sprint

My team want to measure the Points Commitment Reliability metric, witch is as simple as the points delivered in sprint vs the points planned to be delivered.

In fact, we have two queries showing it but separately, and we want to know if is posible to have a percentage visualization of the rate of those metrics in Visual Studio Team Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through Power BI.

1. [Connect using OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/powerbi/access-analytics-power-bi?view=vsts)
2. Choose WorkItems entry
3. Expand Iteration record to Iteration.Path.

Then you can filter by Iteration path and work item state.

On the other hand, you can do it programming. [Connect using Power Query and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/powerbi/data-connector-functions?view=vsts).

For example, call REST API by calling `VSTS.AccountContents("REST API URL")`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not any official widget or chart to handle your requirement.

Since you already created two queries to get related data info. Then as a workaroundm you could **export the query to excel**,  create the chart or table in excel based on your needs, calculate and display the completion percentage.

Just create table/chart in Excel manually to make a division between two queries.

Below articles for your reference:

- [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel)
- [Create Excel reports from a work item query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/excel/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports)

Comment: There is not workarround even using Power Bi connector?

Comment: @JosbelLuna Haven't tried this, we do not have this kind of build-in widget. But it's able to  Connect to VSTS with Power BI Data Connector, take a look at this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=vsts,  you could track the info in Power BI side.

Comment: Didn't update the post, starian's solution works perfect for us because we are already connected with power bi, and querying there is more flexible than VSTS.